# show title for nonmembers

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to show the recent posts which are restricted by using paid membership pro plugin.So that users can see the recent posts and when they click they can see that the post is for paid registrations and then they register and see the content

Answer (score 0):

How have you restricted them to just paid users? That info would be helpful.

Alternatively you could just do a database query to get a list of the latest posts that have post_type = post and post_status = published and then do a foreach statement to iterate through each one.

More WP DB info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb